# programmatically add custom css design tokens to material-ui components

Tags: css, react-redux, material-ui, adobe-xd

I'm using material-ui components in my react-redux app. I had created the UI prototype using adobe-xd, which provides an option to export the character styles (design tokens) in the form of a css file:

```
:root {

/* Colors: */
--text-color: #F8E29F;
--unnamed-color-6c63ff: #6C63FF;
--message-bar-avatar-panel: #3F4851;
--name-text: #A6BCD0;
--eth-subtext-stars: #748A9D;
--navbar-footer-stars-bg: #232323;
--unnamed-color-7b8188: #7B8188;
--bg-drawer: #101010;

/* Font/text values */
--unnamed-font-family-fira-sans: Fira Sans;
--unnamed-font-family-abril-fatface: Abril Fatface;
--unnamed-font-style-light: Light;
--unnamed-font-style-regular: Regular;
--unnamed-font-size-7: 7px;
--unnamed-font-size-8: 8px;
--unnamed-font-size-14: 14px;
--unnamed-font-size-16: 16px;
--unnamed-font-size-24: 24px;
--unnamed-font-size-28: 28px;
--unnamed-font-size-32: 32px;
--unnamed-character-spacing-0: 0px;
--unnamed-character-spacing-0-96: 0.96px;
--unnamed-character-spacing-1-15: 1.15px;
--unnamed-character-spacing-1-31: 1.31px;
--unnamed-line-spacing-10: 10px;
--unnamed-line-spacing-12: 12px;
--unnamed-line-spacing-20: 20px;
--unnamed-line-spacing-24: 24px;
--unnamed-line-spacing-32: 32px;
}

/* Character Styles */
.text-ultra-small-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-fira-sans);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-light);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-7);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-20);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-0);
color: var(--name-text);
}
.text-very-small-dim-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-fira-sans);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-light);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-8);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-10);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-0);
color: var(--eth-subtext-stars);
}
.text-very-small-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-fira-sans);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-light);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-8);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-12);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-0);
color: var(--name-text);
}
.text-small-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-fira-sans);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-light);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-14);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-20);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-0);
color: var(--text-color);
}
.text-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-fira-sans);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-light);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-16);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-24);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-0);
color: var(--text-color);
}
.drawer-menu-items-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-fira-sans);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-light);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-16);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-24);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-0);
color: var(--unnamed-color-7b8188);
}
.text-secondary-dim-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-fira-sans);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-light);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-16);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-24);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-0);
color: var(--eth-subtext-stars);
}
.text-secondary-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-fira-sans);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-light);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-16);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-24);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-0);
color: var(--name-text);
}
.text-secondary-bold-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-fira-sans);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-regular);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-16);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-24);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-0);
color: var(--name-text);
}
.heading-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-abril-fatface);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-regular);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-24);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-32);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-0-96);
color: var(--text-color);
}
.title-mobile- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-abril-fatface);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-regular);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-28);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-32);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-1-15);
color: var(--text-color);
}
.title-web- {
font-family: var(--unnamed-font-family-abril-fatface);
font-style: var(--unnamed-font-style-regular);
font-size: var(--unnamed-font-size-32);
line-height: var(--unnamed-line-spacing-32);
letter-spacing: var(--unnamed-character-spacing-1-31);
color: var(--text-color);
}
```

is there some way that I can programmatically import this custom CSS values for character-styles (and color styles) to reflect in all my material-ui components?, like design tokens injection of sorts? everytime i make changes to the adobe-xd prototypes and save a new css, it should import the values from that css and reflect in the material-ui components. You can also suggest if there is a better way to implement design tokens from prototype (adobe-xd) to codebase (react UI frameworks)

Answer (score 0):

use Css Import on your File and Put Css From Adobe Xd Share tab to Advanced Export plugin to Variable.Css

Comment: can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: adobexd share tab ? and advanced export plugin for adobe xd ? you can search them